# How to open any file from a textfield?

Tags: java, swing, file

So I don't want to have the textfeild open a text file, read it, and copy its contents into it. I do not want that.

What I am wondering is how I could open any sort of file using this textfield. I have tried this code and it does not work:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Console extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

TextArea c = new TextArea("", 30,30, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
JTextField command = new JTextField(2);

public Console(String title) {
    super(title);

    c.setEditable(false);
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    c.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    c.setFont(new Font("Courier", 12, 16));
    c.setText("Booted up the console" + "\n" + "Enter a command...");

    command.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    command.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    command.setFont(new Font("Courier", 12, 16));

    add(c, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(command, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    command.addKeyListener(this);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) { 
        String COMMAND = command.getText();
        String otherCommand = command.getText();
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        File file = new File(otherCommand);
        String f = file.toString();
        if (COMMAND.equals("open")) {
            c.append("\n" + "Enter file to open:");
            if(otherCommand.equals(f)) {
                try {
                    desktop.open(file);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    c.append("Invalid file location");
                }
            }

        }
        if (COMMAND.equals("exit")) {
            c.append("\n" + "Exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){

}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){

}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){

}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){

}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){

}
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

The main thing I have having trouble is in this bit of code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) { 
            String COMMAND = command.getText();
            String otherCommand = command.getText();
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            File file = new File(otherCommand);
            String f = file.toString();
            if (COMMAND.equals("open")) {
                c.append("\n" + "Enter file to open:");
                if(otherCommand.equals(f)) {
                    try {
                        desktop.open(file);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        c.append("Invalid file location");
                    }
                }

            }
            if (COMMAND.equals("exit")) {
                c.append("\n" + "Exiting...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: open doesn't exist.
at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
at com.parth.Console.keyPressed(Console.java:52)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Never, never, never add a KeyListener to a JTextField. Ever. Use an ActionListener instead as this will allow the listener to respond when the user is done entering data, and then presses `<enter>`. But yeah, as @AndyTurner mentions, you're trying to open a non-existent file.

Comment: Erm, does the file you're trying to open exist? What is the name of that file?

Comment: Also you're getting text from the JTextField **before** the user has a chance of entering anything.

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Some problems with your code:

```
command.addKeyListener(this);
```

You'll want to avoid using KeyListeners for most Swing key-related codes as it's a low-level listener and is only active when a component has focus. Even more of an issue is uding it within a JTextField since doing so can block some key core behaviors  of the JTextField. Better to use a DocumentListener, but actually in your case, much better to use an ActionListener.

Regarding:

```
String COMMAND = command.getText();
String otherCommand = command.getText();
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
File file = new File(otherCommand);
String f = file.toString();
if (COMMAND.equals("open")) {
    c.append("\n" + "Enter file to open:");
    if (otherCommand.equals(f)) {
        try {
            desktop.open(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            c.append("Invalid file location");
        }
    }
}
```

Here you're getting text from the command JTextField **before** the user has entered any new text.

Regarding:

```
public class Console extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
```

You are painting yourself in a corner by having your class extend JFrame, forcing you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture that most of the Swing GUI code that I've created and that I've seen does **not** extend JFrame, and in fact it is rare that you'll ever want to do this. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

Also, you will want to not have your GUI classes implement your listener interfaces as that is giving a class too much varied responsibility. Either use an anonymous inner class or private inner class, or if involved a separate stand-alone class for your listener.

---

What you want to do is again use an ActionListener, and change its state depending on what the user entered. If the user entered "open", then perhaps set an openFile boolean to true, and within the listener, if true, on the next time `actionPerformed` is called, the String obtained will be used to open a file. Or you could use an enum to hold the ActionListener's state. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Console2 extends JPanel {
    private static final String INTRO_TEXT = "Booted up the console" + "\n"
            + "Enter a command...\n";
    private static final String ENTER_FILE_PROMPT = "Enter file to open:\n";
    private static final String OPEN = "open";
    private static final String EXIT = "exit";
    public static final String USER_PROMPT = "User > ";
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(INTRO_TEXT, 20, 40);
    private JTextField inputField = new JTextField();

    public Console2() {
        // have text area wrap lines
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        // have it not get focus
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // ***** this is it! Add an ActionListener to our JTextField. *****
        inputField.addActionListener(new InputListener());

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(inputField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    // listener state
    enum InputState {
        GETTING_COMMAND, OPEN_FILE
    }

    private class InputListener implements ActionListener {
        private InputState state = InputState.GETTING_COMMAND;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get input text and clear the field
            String inputText = inputField.getText().trim();
            inputField.setText("");
            textArea.append(USER_PROMPT + inputText + "\n");
            if (state == InputState.GETTING_COMMAND) {
                if (OPEN.equalsIgnoreCase(inputText)) {
                    state = InputState.OPEN_FILE; // change the listener's state
                    textArea.append(ENTER_FILE_PROMPT); // prompt user
                }
                if (EXIT.equalsIgnoreCase(inputText)) {
                    Window window = SwingUtilities
                            .getWindowAncestor(Console2.this);
                    window.dispose();
                }
            } else if (state == InputState.OPEN_FILE) {
                state = InputState.GETTING_COMMAND; // reset

                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                File file = new File(inputText);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    Component parentComponent = Console2.this;
                    Object message = "File " + file.toString()
                            + " does not exist";
                    String title = "Error Attempting to Open File";
                    int messageType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentComponent, message,
                            title, messageType);
                } else {
                    try {
                        desktop.open(file);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Component parentComponent = Console2.this;
                        Object message = e1.getMessage();
                        String title = "Error Attempting to Open File";
                        int messageType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentComponent, message,
                                title, messageType);
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Console2 mainPanel = new Console2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Console2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Another option is that when "open" is entered, display a JFileChooser to allow the user to choose an existing file.

Comment: *"..display a JFileChooser to allow the user to choose an existing file."*  It is a pity that advice is buried way down the bottom of this excellent answer.  If some app. expected me to type in a file name, I'd want to smack the programmer up-side the head.  *"Won't someone think of the **end user?"*** (said while wringing hands and frowning with worry).

Answer (score 2):

Below message in stack trace,

```
at com.parth.Console.keyPressed(Console.java:52)
```

this corresponds to below line (assuming you have 2 more lines extra in your actual code (package declaration followed by new line?)),

```
desktop.open(file);
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) says that you will get an `IllegalArgumentException` when using `open` method of `Desktop` class when the file is not present.

> IllegalArgumentException - if the specified file doesn't exist

Please do a print of `file.getName()` before you call the `open` method and verify if the file which you are trying to open actually exist